Routing issues in Laravel project
I am working on a Laravel project where I have three types of admins, each with their own login pages. Here are the routes:
// Core Admin Routes
Route::get('/core-admin', [CoreAuthController::class, 'loadLogin']);
Route::post('/core-admin', [CoreAuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/core-admin/dashboard', [CoreAuthController::class, 'coreAdmin']);
    Route::get('/core-admin/logout', [CoreAuthController::class, 'logout']); // Change logout route
});

// Master Admin Routes
Route::get('/master-admin', [MasterAuthController::class, 'loadLogin']);
Route::post('/master-admin', [MasterAuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/master-admin/dashboard', [MasterAuthController::class, 'masterAdmin']);
    Route::get('/master-admin/logout', [MasterAuthController::class, 'logout']); // Change logout route
});

// Website Admin Routes
Route::get('/website-admin', [WebsiteAuthController::class, 'loadLogin']);
Route::post('/website-admin', [WebsiteAuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/website-admin/dashboard', [WebsiteAuthController::class, 'websiteAdmin']);
    Route::get('/website-admin/logout', [WebsiteAuthController::class, 'logout']); // Change logout route
});

The issue I'm facing is that when I log in as a core-admin, I'm redirected to the website-admin/dashboard. I've checked my controller code and it seems fine, so I suspect the issue lies within the route files. Interestingly, if I comment out the route code for the website-admin, I'm then redirected to the master-admin/dashboard. Any insights on what could be causing this?

i think you should provide more details especially regarding your auth middleware , im gonna provide you with an example on how to manage multi role using breeze in laravel
first start by creating the role middleware in /app/Http/Midlleware
class RoleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next ,$role): Response
    {
        if (auth()->user()->role_id != $role) {
            abort(403); // Forbidden access
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}

Then register the middleware
add this code to bootstrap/app

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        //
        $middleware->alias([
            'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
        ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

Then add this function to your user model
to  specify the redirect route of each user based on there role
   public function determineRedirectRoute()
    {
        return match ($this->role_id) {
            //routes names
            1 => 'agents_accounts.index',
            2 => 'accounts.index',
        };
    }

finally modify your route file
///specify the role id for the corresponding route group
Route::middleware(['auth' , 'role:2'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('accounts', [AccountsController::class, 'index'])->name('accounts.index');
});

// another role 
Route::middleware(['auth' , 'role:1'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('agents/accounts', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('agents_accounts.index');

});


Dear It's not work.....

Please provide more details,  and use only one login page and based on the logged user's role redirect them to their home page

I think you need to change the order. I've had a similar problem before. You should try to change the order like this.
// Master Admin Routes
// Website Admin Routes
// Core Admin Routes

Dear it.'s not work...
